# Custom button is not working as expected

Tags: javascript, custom-button

In our organisation we are using zuora for creating quotes & subscriptions.

In opportunity page we had a custom button to create quotes but it's normally routing to custom VF page.

But whenever a user tries to create any quote, the shipping address should not be null. If shipping address = null, then it needs to throw error to user.

So, I created this custom button:

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/30.0/connection.js")} 
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/24.0/apex.js")} 

if(ISBLANK({!Opportunity.Shipping_City__c})){ 
alert("Shipping address should not be null") 
} 
else { 
window.open('https://zqu.cs5.visual.force.com/apex/CreateQuote?oppId={!Opportunity.Id}&quoteType=Subscription&scontrolCaching=1&stepNumber=1');

}
```

Error is coming like

> A problem with the OnClick JavaScript for this button or link was
>   encountered:
>
> ISBLANK is not defined

Why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only use `ISBLANK` and other merge functions *inside* a merge field (`{!...}`).

**Incorrect**

```
if(ISBLANK({!Opportunity.Shipping_City__c})){
```

**Correct**

```
if({!ISBLANK(Opportunity.Shipping_City__c)}){
```

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript doesn't understand `ISBLANK`. Try something like this:

```
if('{!Opportunity.Shipping_City__c}') {
  alert("Shipping address should not be null") 
} 
else { 
  window.open('https://zqu.cs5.visual.force.com/apex/CreateQuote?oppId={!Opportunity.Id}&quoteType=Subscription&scontrolCaching=1&stepNumber=1');

}
```

Comment: Wouldn't you want quotes around that merge expression?